# Deserialize array based polymorphic json in Jackson

Tags: java, kotlin, jackson

I have a json array that contains child objects:

```
[
  ["t", 1, 2, 3],
  ["o", "a", "b"]
]
```

Where "t" and "o" are keys, and other elements in array are data values.
And I want to deserialize this array to classes using these models

```
@JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME, include = JsonTypeInfo.As.WRAPPER_ARRAY)
@JsonSubTypes(
    JsonSubTypes.Type(value = T::class, name = "t"),
    JsonSubTypes.Type(value = O::class, name = "o")
)
@JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.ARRAY)
sealed class A

data class T(val x: Int, val y: Int, val z: Int) : A()
data class O(val a: String, val b: String) : A()
```

When I do

```
println(json.writeValueAsString(T(1, 2, 3)))
```

I receive

```
[ "t", [ 1, 2, 3 ] ]
```

How to flatten nested array to outer array ?

Actual: `["t", [ 1, 2, 3 ]]`

Expected: `["t", 1, 2, 3]`

Comment: this is valid json

Comment: @LppEdd could you elaborate? I don't see anything invalid about the json on the question.

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt I was referring to the first example. But I was wrong anyway. Don't mind my comment. I got confused with { and [

Comment: That's just what `WRAPPER_ARRAY` does: "a 2-element JSON array: first element is the serialized type identifier, and second element the serialized POJO as JSON Object". Try `PROPERTY` instead (not an answer because I can't check it at the moment).

Comment: @AlexeyRomanov, it does not work for `PROPERTY` as well, probably custom serialiser / deserialiser should be introduced.